# Expressing the sum of two matrix commutators as a matrix commutator

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to show by elementary means that the sum of two matrix commutators is a matrix commutator? That is, say $M = AB - BA$ and $M' = CD - DC$, can we somehow explicitly show that $M + M'$ is a commutator? $A, B, C, D$ are all $n \times n$ square matrices over $\mathbb R$. Something like say $(A + B)(C + D) - (C + D)(A + B)$ (but that itself is obviously not valid).

I do know the result that all traceless matrices can be expressed as commutators, but I don't want to use it here and am rather looking for simple algebraic manipulation.

Comment: I recommend that you look for something that works in the case that $A,B,C,D$ all have rank $1$ and try to extend it to a general formula

Comment: I suspect this might be a bit optimistic.